# JS/JQuery : Value from select OR from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want my user to select a value from a `<select>` component, but if he can't find the right value in the `<select>` i'd like him to be able to input a value himself.

I know how to do this in a dirty way : if he click a check-box I deactivate the `<select>` and activate a text input on the side of the select. With angular JS I can even make the select disappear and be replaced by a text input.

But, is there single component that would let me solve this problem without addind a checkbox to tick (the space is limited on the page and I'd like to save some) ?

Comment: I don't think that an html control like that exists. Maybe you want to give your user an input instead of the select and then toggle auto-complete, or just add an option (none of the above) and right next to the select put an input where the user can add his own value.

Comment: You could try to do something with fancy CSS3 selectors, but that would only work in the latest browsers, I think. Therefore I would use Javascript for it. To add a checkbox is unnecessary for this. Check my answer for the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an option in the select dropdown like `My option is not in the list` with the value `0` (or what ever you prefere) and have a change event attached to the select. When the value of the select changes to 0 you could replace the select with an text input field using jQuerys `replceWith` function: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Edit: I made a little fiddle, this should be more understandable than the above one ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/azumon0L/
Note: You can use any name for the text input, here I just assumed, that you want the same as in the Select...

Edit2: It wasn't specified, that the user should be able to get back to the select and because I'm a lazy bastard, it didn't add it. However I've updated my solution, now it is able to do what you want! http://jsfiddle.net/azumon0L/2/

Comment: Nice idea but there is no way back, if the user miss click  he has to reload the page :s. I think I'll have to add a check box anyway :(

Comment: @IggY check the update here: http://jsfiddle.net/azumon0L/2/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @IggY did my solution help? If yes, it would be nice, if you could accept the answer, if not just let me know, how I can help improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is that you provide both **select dropdown** and **textbox** in Design of page.
Whenever user selects option from select dropdown, the value of option should be filled into textbox. This can be done via jquery change event of select input.
And if user does not finds required option from select dropdown, user can input value in textbox.

In this way, value of textbox can be used for storing in database.